# ¿Como redireccionar con login en laravel 5.4 con entrust y adminlte?

Tags: laravel

Estoy empezando con laravel ya pase por la parte de manejo del `blade` usando `adminlte` como practica y ahora estoy empezando la parte de roles y permisos de usuarios para eso e elegido usar `entrust` y todo va muy bien excepto en una cosa, no entiendo muy bien como hacer para después del login me redirija a donde deseo según  el tipo de usuario pensaba que con hacerlo en route  podría hacerlo pero no me esta resultando.

Me gustaría saber si alguien aquí sabe una manera de después de `login` el verifique el rol y lo redireccione a la ruta correcta? o algún link o algo por que e visto muchas guías de como instalar `enstrust` pero ninguna de como hacer esta parte algunas sugieren.

```
Route::group(['prefix' => 'admin', 'middleware' => ['role:admin']], function() {
    Route::get('/admin', 'AdminController@index');
});
```

Pero no me esta funcionando no redirecciona a donde deseo me sigue enviando a /home (que esta por defecto en adminlte).

Comment: ¿cuál es la ruta correcta?

Answer (score 1):

puedes intentar sobre escribir el método authenticate del controlador AuthController, también te sugiero revisar la documentación https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication#authenticating-users

```
public function authenticate(Request $request)
{
    if (Auth::attempt(['email' => $request->email, 'password' => $request->password])) {
        return (Auth::user()->role->id == $someValue) ? redirect()->intended('/admin') : redirect()->intended('/home') ;
    } else {
        return redirect()->back()
            ->withInput($request->only('email', 'remember'))
            ->withErrors([
                'email' => 'Estas credenciales no coinciden con nuestros registros.'
            ]);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Tienes que cambiar, la Ruta de redirección en el **Middleware** de autenticación.

> RedirectIfAuthenticated.php